# Are all agents identical except for their abilities?

Tags: valorant

I'd like to know if there is any difference between the agents when ignoring their abilities.

Do all agents for example have the same movement speed while running or walking or jumping? Identical weapon handling such as reload time, draw time, recoil?

Basically I'd like to know if the abilities should be the only criteria for choosing an agent, outside of cosmetic differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no differences between the [agents](https://valorant.fandom.com/wiki/Agents) outside of their abilities. All of them will have the same movement speed, weapon handling, and hitboxes.

Each agent gets four unique abilities and one ultimate, and each agent can be categorized as one of four types: Controller, Duelist, Initiator, and Sentinel.

So outside of cosmetics, abilities are the only reason to choose one agent over another. Ideally each team is comprised of a blend of agent types that make up a well rounded team.

Answer (score 1):

Jett can jump in a pretty unique way. That's one thing I like. There is no agent who can jump slowly like Jett and make a soft landing no matter how high you go. And this is not one of those 4 abilities that you need to 'activate'. It works all the time.

There is no difference in normal movement speed.